# Link to load external content into DIV

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/9BCrs/5/

I have this set up to load a file into a DIV using the two links in the left DIV but it requires a unique copy of the same JQuery code each time there is a new link.

Is there a way of connecting the file being called and the DIV it is being called from to the link via some kind of variable maybe so that the code has to be included only once?

```
$(function() {
$(".link1").click(function() {
    $(".load_space").load("helloworld.txt", function() {
        //Insert contents of file wherever
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 200);
        $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
    });
});

$(".link2").click(function() {
    $(".load_space").load("hellouniverse.txt", function() {
        //Insert contents of file wherever
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 200);
        $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
    });
});

$(".link3").click(function() {
    $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 450 }, 200);
    $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.

1. Use a map in your code.

   You could have a map in your code that tells you that `link1` => `helloworld.txt` and `link2` => `hellouniverse.txt`, like this:

   ```
   var map = {
       link1: "helloworld.txt",
       link2: "hellouniverse.txt"
   };
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   $(".link1, .link2").click(function() {
       var file = map[this.className]; // <=== Assumption here, see below
       $(".load_space").load(file, function() {
           //Insert contents of file wherever
           $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 200);
           $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
       });
   });
   ```

   That assumes that the `link1` or `link2` class will be the **only** class on the element. If that won't be the case, you may have to massage `className` a bit before using it to look up the file.
2. Use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

   Add a `data-file` attribute to your `link` elements, e.g.:

   ```
   <div class="link1" data-file="helloworld.txt">...</div>
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   $(".link1, .link2").click(function() {
       var file = $(this).attr('data-file');
       $(".load_space").load(file, function() {
           //Insert contents of file wherever
           $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 200);
           $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
       });
   });
   ```

   or instead of the `$(".link1, .link2")` selector, you could just use `$("*[data-file]")` or better yet, something a bit more targeted (since selecting *purely* on an attribute selector is a bit heavy). So perhaps `$(".links[data-file]")` for any element with class "links" that has a `data-file` attribute.

Comment: Awesome, I'm using #2 but I like both. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function once

```
var load_fct = function() {
    //Insert contents of file wherever
    $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 200);
    $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
}
```

And reuse it where you need it:

```
$(".link1").click(function() {
    $(".load_space").load("helloworld.txt", load_fct);
});
```